# How can a Java method retrieve the method object pertaining to that particular method? (Java)

Tags: java, methods

I am writing a Java method with the following signature.

void Logger(Method method, Object[] args);

If a method (e.g. ABC() ) calls this method Logger, it should retrieve the Method object that encapsulates data about itself (ABC()) and pass it as an argument.

How can a method retrieve the Method object that is storing all the information about that method?

A simple way is that I use 
Method[] methods = ExampleClass.Class.getMethods();
and search the whole array for the Method with the correct name. (Which is quite inefficient). Also, if two or more methods have the same names, then I will have to retrieve their parameter types too (to distinguish them) and have different code for each method. This would be inefficient as well as painful.

Is there a better way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the purpose of all this code wizardry? If you can tell the purpose then maybe someone can suggest a better way to do it rather that all this complicated logic.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it. Rather obtain the method name from the stack.

```
public void log(Object object) {
    String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
    // ...
}
```

This is however pretty expensive and that's why most self-respected logging frameworks offer an option to turn it on/off (which I would recommend to use instead of homegrowing one).

Comment: +1.  I agree that 1) This is the way to do it; and 2) it should be avoided *in general* (though loggers are a good exception).

Comment: I don't want the Method's name. I want its object. The name Logger is deceptive (my mistake). It pushes all the method objects in an arrayList along with their arguments. The arrayList is later traversed and the same methods are called in the same order with the same arguments. So having the objects would be much awesomer. If not the Method Objects, I am fine with getting the Method name and all the arguments too.

Comment: Are you reinventing a testing tramework? If not, did you consider command/strategy pattern? Well, you've got an easy way to get the method name (there's more information in [`StackTraceElement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) as well). Passing the `Method` itself around from inside the calling method isn't nicely possible which would only lead to lot of duplicated clutter in each of the calling methods. By the way, consider using [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) `Object...` instead of `Object[]`.

Comment: How do I populate the varargs object and pass it on to the pseudoLogger function? ............... This is not exactly a testing framework. This is something like a task-queue. If a method cannot be executed when it is called (due to the state of the system), it just pushes itself into a queue and waits for its turn.

Comment: Just enter the method arguments the same way. The varargs only gives the advantage that you don't need to wrap those arguments in an ugly `new Object[]`. As to the functional requirement: you really need to take a look at the command pattern to do the units of task. Then you can just end up with a `Queue<Task>` where `Task` is an `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, don't implement this method at all. Use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), or some other modern logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a wrapper over existing logger frameworks then the already provide a way to print the method name in the log message - if that's what you are trying to implement.

You can read from the log4j documentation, for example, that this extraction (as the other answer suggests) is done from the stack trace and is expensive : http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html